# Indexing Data directly from database Solr 6.5

Tags: database, indexing, solr

I'm new to new Solr. I got the examples of how to index data directly from database for Solr 4.9 but still not able to find anything for Solr 6.5. 
Does Solr 6.5 support database indexing? If yes, then how to achieve same.

Answer (score 1):

DataImportHandler is usually the way to load data from a database into Solr. It was there in Solr 4.9 and is still there in Solr 6.5.

Specifically, Solr ships with a dih example (bin/solr start -e dih) that has a number of collection, one of them showing database indexing.

There are also third party products that can read from database and index into Solr (eg. [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/)), but their levels of Solr support may vary.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre. Got the Solution from dih example.